# Do browsers read css selectors from right to left?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do browsers match CSS selectors from right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left)

I've heard browsers read css selectors from right to left. So if we write like this;

```
#block1 a{text-decoration:none;}
```

browsers find first, all a tag then find block1 and performance drops a bit. Is it true?

Comment: Yes... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327009/in-which-direction-are-css-selectors-matched http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left

Comment: a) That depends on the browser, b) why would performance drop a bit and if so, what are you going to do with that information?

Comment: well, what is true usage of it. Like this? a #block1{text-decoration:none;} ??

Comment: True usage has nothing to do with performance. You either use it a certain way or you don't.

Comment: `a #block1` is something entirely different than `#block1 a`. How browsers evaluate CSS is an irrelevant internal detail, it doesn't change how CSS and selector rules works.

Comment: @dystroy: I meant in general. Whether that is still true I have no idea because I'm not an implementer, but what I do know is that there are many optimizations that are employed beyond the general RTL matching algorithm, and that **none of this should matter to authors at all**.

Comment: I found an article on the subject https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Writing_Efficient_CSS